# MySQL like and total with node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

I use node + express to create REST API paging and fuzzy query interface. When I query the product name of `全脂牛奶` and total is 16.Whether it is mysql limit，`COUNT(*)` is 16. I can see the total number of query results, MySQL paging at the same time the total number of records，but I do not know how to do it?

#### I hope to expect the JSON data result:

```json
{
  results: [{
      id: 10,
      title: "a",
      price: 99
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      title: "b",
      price: 139
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      title: "c",
      price: 109
    }
  ],
  total: 16
}
```

#### When query the `全脂牛奶`，`total` is 16.

[image]

#### pageNum is 1. It should be 16

[image]

#### pageNum is 2. It should be 16

[image]

#### My code:

```js
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'mynode'
});
connection.connect();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Get product list page + fuzzy query
app.get('/good', function(req, res) {
  var total; //total pages     
  var search = req.query.search; //query
  var param = req.query || req.params;
  var pageNum = parseInt(param.pageNum || 1); // page number
  var end = parseInt(param.pageSize || 3); // The default number of pages
  var start = (pageNum - 1) * end;
  var limit = start + ',' + end;

  connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goods WHERE title like '%" + search + "%' LIMIT " + limit, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    var data = {
      results: results,
      total: total
    };
    res.json(data);
  });

});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("✔ Express server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear  .. update your question add  your atbel schema ,,a proper tabular data sample and the tabular expected result too

Comment: Here in `SELECT count(*)` you are retrieving just count of records filtered. If you need to get records' details you need to fetch all the fields and get their amount later with JS(it's really easy just like `total: results.length`)

Comment: @skyboyer I am sorry and I just revised it.